# ASP.NET Details View. How to bind a value not in the Object Data Source

Tags: asp.net, binding, detailview

I have an ASP.NET DetailsView bound to an Object Data Source (ODS). I have method for the ODS OnSelecting event and in this method based on fields coming back from the Object Data Source we do another database lookup to get a 'Risk' value for the record.

My question is how to I bind/eval and display this  additional 'Risk' field , I've been finding it difficult because it's not put of the datasource bound to the detailsview.

I've tried just adding a Label control to the DetailsView ItemTemplate but you can't add an ID to the control to reference it in the code behind.  Any ideas?

Update here's some code

Here some simple example code of what I'm trying to do

```
 <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
        <Fields>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div style="float: right">
                        <asp:Label  runat="server" Text="NEED RISK HERE"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
                        Text="Update" />
                    &nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonCancelUpdates" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
                        Text="Cancel" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" OnSelecting="ods1_Selecting"
        SelectMethod="GetMemoryDataTable" TypeName="AspMemoryDatatableDemo.MemoryDataTableProvider">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Code Behind

```
  public String GetRisk()
    {
        return "HIGH";
    }


    protected void ods1_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
      // Get Risk based on row data
      // Need some way of showing this in the DetailsView

        GetRisk();
    }
```

[image]

The dataset will actually be coming from the data entity, but in this example I just use a in memory datatable.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to help you here, but it would really help if you showed us some code for an issue like this. Have you tried adding a column to the object data source? I'm assuming you have a datatable of some kind (if not, convert it to a datatable). So let's just add a column and re-bind it...

---

### HTML

```
<div>

<asp:GridView id="myGridView" AutoGenerateColumns="true" runat="server">

</asp:GridView>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="column_name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="addColumn" Text="Add Column" runat="server" />
</div>
```

---

### VB.NET

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    ' ===========================================================================
    '  This section is just to create a datatable. I assume you are already have one 
    '      that gets retrieved from a database somewhere.
    Dim dt As New DataTable ' create new test datatable

    With dt.Columns ' add columns to datatable
        .Add("id").AutoIncrement = True
        .Add("value")
    End With

    For i = 1 To 4 ' add some rows and values to the datatable.
        Dim msg = String.Empty
        Select Case i
            Case 1
                msg = "this"
            Case 2
                msg = "is"
            Case 3
                msg = "a test"
            Case 4
                msg = "table"
        End Select
        Dim r As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
        r("value") = msg
        dt.Rows.Add(r)
    Next i
    ' ===========================================================================

    myGridView.DataSource = dt ' set our datasource
    myGridView.DataBind() ' bind our data source

End Sub


Protected Sub addColumn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles addColumn.Click
    Dim dt As DataTable = DirectCast(myGridView.DataSource, DataTable) ' get the current datatable used by your gridview.
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(column_name.Text) Then ' check if the new column name is null or empty.
        dt.Columns.Add(column_name.Text).DefaultValue = "new value" ' just here to add a default value. yours presumably will already have a value.
        myGridView.DataSource = dt ' update the datasource.
        myGridView.DataBind() ' bind the new datasource.

    End If
End Sub
```

---

### PAGE BEFORE ADDING COLUMN

[image: Before]

---

### PAGE AFTER ADDING COLUMN

[image: After]

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question with some example code, might help.  The dataset that I'm binding the ODS to is coming from the entity framework and is just a database view.  I notice that in your example your adding a new column to your datatable. Do I some how need to add a new field to my entity, or in my example the datatable

Comment: @Hevski a database "view" is still a table of data being returned. Regardless, I'm pretty sure anything displayed in a dataview or gridview can be formatted as a DataTable and therefore can have rows and/or columns added to it. If you want more control over what you're displaying, create an ASP Web API controller, in it make your database connection and get/fill a datatable, then serialize it using Newtonsoft's json.net library, return it to the API caller, and then render the table via javascript. I started doing this instead of using ASP long ago and it works great.